# Find percentage of sessions that include view of a single URL

Tags: google-analytics

It's easy enough to find the percentage of views a single page has, but I'm trying to find percentage of sessions that include a view of a single URL.

Or if the above isn't possible, the percentage of users that view of a single URL would do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the behavior reports, "Site Content", "All Pages". Search for the url you want and then look at the "Unique pageview" column. Despite the "pageview" moniker this is actually a session level metric and gives the number of visits that have visited this url at least once.

Or you can create a custom report and include "page" as dimension and "unique pageview" as metric. You can filter the report to display only the urls you want (without filters you will get a report for all urls, ordered by the metric in the first column - in this case, unique pageviews).